# Java NIO BufferUnderflowException when using DatagramChannels and Serialization

Tags: java, serialization, udp, nio, channel

I am trying to write a program to send and receive a serialized object over a Datagram channel using Java nio, but I am receiving a BufferUnderFlow exception when trying to read my object from the ObjectInputStream.

Currently I have the following code:

Sender:

```
public void sendMessage(InetSocketAddress destination) {
    writeBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(64000);
    writeBuffer.clear();
    /*
     * Put new MyObject into a ByteArrayOutputStream and put that
     * into the writeBuffer to be sent.
     */
    MyObject myObject = new MyObject();
    byteArrayOS = new ByteArrayOutputStream(writeBuffer.capacity());
    objectOS = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOS);
    objectOS.writeObject(myObject);
    objectOS.flush();

    writeBuffer.put(byteArrayOS.toByteArray());
    writeBuffer.flip();
    channel.send(writeBuffer, new InetSocketAddress(ipAddress, portNum));
    // Channel is bound to correct IP / Port
}
```

Receiver:

```
public void read() {
  try { //blah blah
    channel = DatagramChannel.open();
    channel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(readPort));
    channel.configureBlocking(true);

    ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayIS = null;
    ObjectInputStream objectIS = null;
    MyObject object;
    while (true) {
        inputBuffer.clear();
    client.getChannel().receive(inputBuffer);
    byte[] data = new byte[inputBuffer.capacity()];
    inputBuffer.get(data);
        /*
         * Troubleshooting: inputBuffer is returning with something
         */
        byteArrayIS = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        objectIS = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayIS);
        myObject = objectIS.readObject(); // Throwing BufferUnderflowException here
        // Process object
        // ...
    }
  } catch (BlahBlah e) {}
}
```

This is the exception I am getting:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.BufferUnderflowException
        at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.get(HeapByteBuffer.java:145)
        at java.nio.ByteBuffer.get(ByteBuffer.java:694)
        at package.Class.main(Class.java:493)
```

What is causing this BufferUnderflowException to be thrown? I can't figure it out. Both ByteBuffers are allocated the same amount of space, and the writeBuffer is not overflowing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to flip() the buffer to get data out of it. NB you should be using limit(), not capacity(), in that line.

Comment: Which buffer do I need to flip and where?

Comment: The one you're getting data out of. The one that is underflowing when you get data out of it. The one you received into. Surely this is obvious?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've been coding for literally about 36 hours at this point for a school project that was way more ambitious than it should have been. I believe I tried flipping it earlier to no avail, but I decided to switch to DatagramSockets and threads to keep it simple and just get it done. Thank you for the help though, Ill give you the upvote later if it works!